# Use esc_attr() to print month name in French

Tags: date

I am working on a PHP code in which I want to display month name in French.

```
 <?php 
 if (false !== strpos($translated_tz['diff'], '-')) {
            $ts = date_sub($altered_timestamp, date_interval_create_from_date_string($translated_tz['diff']));
 } else {
            $ts = date_add($altered_timestamp, date_interval_create_from_date_string($translated_tz['diff']));
 }
 ?>
 <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') {    

 <?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'j F ')) . '<span>' . esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i')) . '</span>'; ?>  // Line A

 <?php } ?>
```

Code at Line A displays the following (**in which month name is in English**):

```
 20 November 03:56
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the PHP code above so that it displays month name in French.

Comment: try the function [date_i18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n)

Comment: @Kaperto I am wondering if you can give me brief pointer how we can achieve that through `date_i18n`.

Comment: esc_attr() is a function for escaping strings. It's not a translation function.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, which has been tested and works:

```
// Timestamp to format (defaults to current time)
$timestamp = time();

// Set language code
$dateformat = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'fr_FR', // Use valid Locale format
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);

// Set date format
$dateformat->setPattern('MMMM');

// Echo (and capitalize) formatted timestamp
echo ucfirst( $dateformat->format( $timestamp ) );
```

It seems that many valid locales can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273